# Slurm: Why do we need Srun in Sbatch script file?

Tags: slurm

I am new to Slurm and I also found the related questions about this topic. However, I am still confused about several points of how to use srun. According to the official document, srun will typically first allocate resources and then run the parallel jobs. For example, I want to run 20 tasks and if I submit my job based on the following script, I am not sure how many tasks are created. Because sbatch only takes care of allocating resources instead of executing program.

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -n 20
#SBATCH --mpi=pmi2
#SBATCH -o myoutputfile.txt
module load mpi/mpich-x86_64
mpirun mpiprogram < inputfile.txt
```

If I am trying to run sequential program like the following, I am not whether there will be a difference or not. For example, I can simply remove the srun command in this script. What will happen?

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -N 1
srun tar zxf julia-0.3.11.tar.gz
echo "prefix=/software/julia-0.3.11" > julia/Make.user
cd julia
srun make
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example will spawn 20 tasks ; `sbatch` will request 20 CPUs **and also set up the environment so** that `mpirun` knows how many CPUs were requested for the job. `mpirun` will then spawn as many processes as were allocated (provided that OpenMPI was compiled with Slurm support).

The `#SBATCH --mpi=pmi2` part is meant for `srun` so it will have no effect if `srun` is not called in the submission script.

In the second example, there will be no difference in the number of processes spawned as only one is needed. But, with `srun`, the output of `sstat` will be more reliable, the management of signals will be more precise, and the buffering of the output will be more controlled (via the `srun` command line options).

If you request multiple tasks, `srun` will instantiate that many processes. It can be an MPI program, or a sequential program that adapts its behaviour based on the `SLURM_PROC_ID` environment variable.

Also you can run multiple `srun` in the same submission script. Each instance of `srun` (called a "step") is then accounted separately in the accounting (`sacct`).

Finally, `srun` can use a subset of the allocation and organise the micro-scheduling of many small tasks in a single job (see the example in the `srun` manpage).